# Simplify how this node.js function is called

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I am using node.js restify.

The code below works fine.

```
var server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'myapp',
    version: '1.0.0'
});

server.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var users;

    // if (/* some condition determining whether the resource requires authentication */) {
    //    return next();
    // }

    users = {
        foo: {
            id: 1,
            password: 'bar'
        }
    };

    // Ensure that user is not anonymous; and
    // That user exists; and
    // That user password matches the record in the database.
    if (req.username == 'anonymous' || !users[req.username] || req.authorization.basic.password !== users[req.username].password) {
        // Respond with { code: 'NotAuthorized', message: '' }
        next(new restify.NotAuthorizedError());
    } else {
        next();
    }

    next();
});
```

What I want is to convert the chunk of function code in `server.use(function (req, res, next) { ...` such that I can call the function in a manner like this `server.use(verifyAuthorizedUser(req, res, next));`

So, what I did was to create this function;

```
function verifyAuthorizedUser(req, res, next)
{
    var users;

    // if (/* some condition determining whether the resource requires authentication */) {
    //    return next();
    // }

    users = {
        foo: {
            id: 1,
            password: 'bar'
        }
    };

    // Ensure that user is not anonymous; and
    // That user exists; and
    // That user password matches the record in the database.
    if (req.username == 'anonymous' || !users[req.username] || req.authorization.basic.password !== users[req.username].password) {
        // Respond with { code: 'NotAuthorized', message: '' }
        next(new restify.NotAuthorizedError());
    } else {
        next();
    }

    next();
}//function verifyAuthorizedUser(req, res, next)
```

Then, I call `server.use(verifyAuthorizedUser(req, res, next));`. Unfortunately, I encountered this error `ReferenceError: req is not defined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the function itself, not a call to the function:

`server.use(verifyAuthorizedUser);`

Edit: more details:

- `verifyAuthorizedUser(req, res, next)` is a **call** to the function `verifyAuthorizedUser`. Its value would be the return value of that function. And it would require `req`, `res`, and `next` to be defined, which they are not.
- you could write:

  ```
  server.use(function(req,res,next)
  {
      verifyAuthorizedUser(req, res, next);
  });
  ```

but that's just adding extra code for no good reason.

- `server.use(verifyAuthorizedUser());` also is a **call** to the function, and you have the additional issue that you're not passing any parameters to a function that is expecting some, so it will obviously crash.

Some functions (such as `restify.queryParser`) may return a function, in which case you would call the first function (with `()`) to get the function to use as a callback.

Comment: May I ask why is `server.use(verifyAuthorizedUser(req, res, next));` wrong? I tried `server.use(verifyAuthorizedUser() );`, it is wrong too. Why is this so when I see so many code examples that looks like this `server.use(restify.queryParser());` which end the function with `()`?

Comment: Added a few more explanations.

Comment: `restify.queryParser()` returns ("creates") a function which has the `req, res, next` arguments.

Comment: @jcaron, thank you very much for the extra explanations. Too bad I can only give you 1 vote instead of 10 votes.

Answer (score 1):

Try `server.use(verifyAuthorizedUser)` instead. This callback function will be passed all the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to parse the parameters in a callback. Just do

```
server.use(verifyAuthorizedUser)
```

for more information, check [here](http://callbackhell.com/)